# Angular 6 - Custom pipes in shared module not being exported

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe, ng-modules

My Angular architecture is composed of 3 modules.

- `AppModule` (where the app prensetation and logic resides)
- `CoreModule` (Contains my services to access API)
- `SharedModule` (Contains my models, pipes, directives, etc...)

I want to add a new pipe in my `SharedModule`, so I create it and then add it to the `declarations` and `exports` fields of the `SharedModule`'s `NgModule` decorator.

Then, in my `AppModule`, I import the `SharedModule` and should have access to my pipes. But, there the thing, I can't. Instead, I have the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   The pipe 'rankingposition' could not be found

There is the code:

**rankingposition.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({ name: 'rankingposition' })
export class RankingPositionPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, ...args: any[]) {
        // Do stuff    
    }
}
```

**shared.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { RankingPositionPipe } from "@app/shared/pipes/ranking-position.pipe";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [RankingPositionPipe],
    exports: [RankingPositionPipe]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
...
import { SharedModule } from '@app/shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
    ...,
    SharedModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [...]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Edit: Add my component code:

**ranking.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { CharacterModel } from "@app/shared/models/character.model";

@Component({
    selector: 'ranking',
    templateUrl: './ranking.component.html'
})
export class RankingComponent {
    public characters: Array<CharacterModel>;

    constructor() {
        this.characters = new Array<CharacterModel>();
    }
}
```

**ranking.component.html**

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    Ranking
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let character of characters; let i = index">
        {{ character.level | rankingposition }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: Do you use that pipe in component declared directly in `AppModule`?

Comment: you has import { RankingPositionPipe } from " **@app** /shared/pipes/ranking-position.pipe"; I think that must be from ./shared/pipes/ranking-position.pipe

Comment: The author may have [set up a TypeScript import path alias](https://decembersoft.com/posts/say-goodbye-to-relative-paths-in-typescript-imports/).

Comment: @AlexPeters Indeed, I've set path alises in my tsconfig.json.

Comment: Can you try directly declaring the rankingposition pipe in declarations of App Module?

Comment: That's odd, I've added the `RankingPositionPipe` to the `AppModule` declarations array and still have the same error.

Comment: You said 'Yes the RankingComponent belongs to the AppModule. It is imported in another module named  AppRoutingModule that defines the routes of the application'. In that case you should import the Pipe in `AppRoutingModule`

Comment: I have imported the `SharedModule` into the `AppRoutingModule` where the components of my app are defined and it works now. So, all pipes and directives **must** be declared in the same module as the components right ?

Comment: Can you add an answer to your question explaining what was wrong and how did you've fixed it? 10x